# Customize Bootstrap's Tab class li .active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following piece of code based on Twitter's Bootstrap:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="border-bottom-color: black">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I was able to customize almost all of its css to my needs.

The part I'm stuck at is the `<li class="active">`, what would be the css rule to overwrite it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.nav.nav-tabs > li.active {
    color: red;
}
```

I think that should do it, or if you only want to target the li in that particular nav

```
#myTab > li.active {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override it only for this particular navigation, you can simply include the ID to the CSS rule:

```
#myTab > li.active{
    /* Your CSS goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`li.active` is the rule for that tag. Remember that css rules are run in the order that the files are linked, so if you want to overwrite it, just add `li.active` rules in a css file that is linked *after* bootstrap.css. You could also just edit bootstrap.css